# (Best Practice) How to send Newsletters?

Tags: php, newsletter

What's the best solution to send an email to 5.000 guys with PHP?

is a simple Loop enough? should i split them and add a cron every 5 minutes?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+bulk+mail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending bulk email in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320512/sending-bulk-email-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bulk mail system, basically it works processing a queue. A simple Loop will take a long time consuming, perheps the host think it is a kind of spam and close the connection. Take a look at **bulk mail system** there are a plenty of in the market, even good open source programs.