# How to set SMTP details in script?

Tags: php, email, smtp

As e-mails sent from my website usually go into Junk, I wanted to edit php.ini file to fix it, but it is not allowed by my hosting provider. They offered their own solution for this:

> The solution we can offer you is to use SMTP for your mailservice.
>
> You can do that by setting any script you are using to SMTP service
>   with the below details:
>
> **Incoming mailserver:** mail.website.com 
>   **Outgoing mailserver:** mail.website.com 
>   **Username:** email account set with your domain 
>   **Password:** your email account password.

I do have couple of .php scripts that send e-mails, but I don't know how to edit SMTP details in them. So how would I do that?

Thank You ))

Comment: what are you using to send mail? ie. are you using PHP mailer?

Comment: yes I am, specificaly I use php mail()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118154/sending-mass-email-using-php/1118190#1118190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use PHPMailer for sending the mails. You will get it here at:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Advanced setup configuration for SMTP can be configured from the script itself if you are using PHPMailer. Detailed guide can be found here:

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: why should I use PHPMailer? I mean I don't need to use Gmail acounts as I have my own mail server.

Comment: sorry i should not have written "should". i wanted to show you the way incase you are using phpmailer. Just seen in your previous comment that you don't.