# How To setup a Mass Mail server using php / Linux?

Tags: php, linux, email, sendmail, mail-server

What is required to set an mass mail sever using Linux and php  , and where can i find some steps for that , what do you recommend .

Best Regards

Comment: Find steps on Google........

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about _specific_ problems, not general how-to stuff like this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out those links,

1. [Sending mass email using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118154/sending-mass-email-using-php)
2. [Mass mail using PHP from my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783404/mass-mail-using-php-from-my-web-application)
3. [How to build a bulk email sending application in php](http://www.slideshare.net/bngsudheer/how-to-build-a-bulk-email-sending-application-in-php)
4. [How to setup a bulk email sender program](http://www.webmastertools.fm/how-to/How+to+set+up+a+Bulk+email+sender+program)

May this help you.

Comment: Thank you the links are great