# Is it possible to trigger a cron on form submission?

Tags: php, email, cron, phpmailer

I have a form with a mail template, that needs to be sent to a large number of users on form submission. Can I send the mails without using sleep() method by setting a `cron` job or something? I'm planning to sent the mail for a set of users in a loop (50 mails/cron) at a time. Or is there any best way to do this?

On research i found this ([Sending mass email using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118154/sending-mass-email-using-php)) which suggests cron as a solution(from many answers that found to be suitable for my case),but even if i set crob file , i need this to be execute only after form is submitted . How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118154/sending-mass-email-using-php

Comment: Don't send 50 mails. Send only one to yourself and add all 50 recipients as BCC.

Comment: If you have the same mail content for all the users you could just create the mail content in a separate PHP file. Then just include the file when sending a mail. I think you don't need a form when the cron job runs.